How to make custom error handling with Nextjs and prisma
For example I don't want to put prisma function in the route handler like this:
export async function GET(req, res) {
  const skills = await prisma.skills.findMany({});
  if (!skills) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: "No skills found" }, { status: 500 });
  }
  return NextResponse.json(skills);
}

So I just separate it and implement and import them services folder,
Problem is I get the error message from there but not with error code (404, 401, 500)
export async function GET(req: NextRequest,
  res: NextResponse) {
  const skills = await getAllSkills();
  if (!skills) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: "No skills found" }, { status: 500 });
  }
  return NextResponse.json(skills);
}

In such case I get a 500 response status in a not found error
And I failed implementing my own custom error classes or middleware, and all the tutorials just put prisma stuff inside of route functions.
I tried to implement my own custom error classes or middleware as in expressjs but i failed with that, and all the tutorials just put prisma stuff inside of route functions.

Please provide more information on the solutions you found and tried so we can help you fix them if they are not working

are you trying to make a new status code? like 502 or 540?
or error message to show to your client?

I edited the question. All I want is to send the right response status code with separation of concerns in my code
